# Is there a way to replicate some data not all data in db by sql server replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I want to replicate some of data that exists in my database. I want to replicate specified data. Is there a solution?

Comment: do mean replication of selective tables or selective columns within a table ?

Comment: I mean selective records for replication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USe Replication [Row Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx):

> Using static **row filters**, you can
>   choose a subset of rows to be
>   published. All Subscribers to a
>   filtered publication receive the same
>   subset of rows for the filtered table

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms151775.e4e1c995-fe81-4c05-b661-39087b323161(en-us,SQL.100).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms151775.e4e1c995-fe81-4c05-b661-39087b323161(en-us,SQL.100).gif)

See also:

- [How to: Define and Modify a Static Row Filter (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152524.aspx)
- [How to: Define and Modify a Parameterized Row Filter for a Merge Article (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152518.aspx)